# SQL: Column count doesn't match row count

Tags: sql, drupal-6

The following query:

```
INSERT INTO term_node( nid, vid, tid )
VALUES (
    (
     SELECT ctb.nid, ctb.vid, 35
     FROM content_type_bout AS ctb
     WHERE field_school_value_c = 'Lafayette'
    )
)
```

Is producing this error:

```
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

`term_node` has only three columns in it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following should work:

```
INSERT INTO term_node( nid, vid, tid )
 SELECT ctb.nid, ctb.vid, 35
 FROM content_type_bout AS ctb
 WHERE field_school_value_c = 'Lafayette'
```

You only use the VALUES clause when you are inserting a single row of data.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which SQL engine you are using, but my hunch is that you are using too many brackets, so it is grouping the 3 columns in to an array and wanting to post them into one column.

Try:

```
INSERT INTO term_node( nid, vid, tid )
VALUES (
     SELECT ctb.nid, ctb.vid, 35
     FROM content_type_bout AS ctb
     WHERE field_school_value_c = 'Lafayette'
)
```

Or even Just:

```
INSERT INTO term_node( nid, vid, tid )
     SELECT ctb.nid, ctb.vid, 35
     FROM content_type_bout AS ctb
     WHERE field_school_value_c = 'Lafayette'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO term_node( nid, vid, tid )
     SELECT ctb.nid, ctb.vid, 35
     FROM content_type_bout AS ctb
     WHERE field_school_value_c = 'Lafayette'
```